# Foldl on a list of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, foldleft

I'm trying to write a function, `pipe` that takes a list of mathematical functions where `pipe [f1,...,fn] x` should return `f1(f2(...(fn x)))` 
I've set it up such that:

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe fs   = foldLeft f base fs
  where
    f a x =    
    base  = 

-- >>> pipe [] 3
-- 3
--
-- >>> pipe [(\x -> x+x), (\x -> x + 3)] 3
-- 12
--
-- >>> pipe [(\x -> x * 4), (\x -> x + x)] 3
-- 24
```

whats the best way to go about this using foldl?
Thanks!

Comment: What do *you* think `foldLeft` and `base` should be? Do you have no intuition at all? PS the function is called `foldl`, there is no such thing as `foldLeft`. (And I'm not convinced this will work as desired with a left fold, although I'd have to think about it - it's usually more natural in Haskell to use a right fold.)

Comment: I'm very new to haskell -- but imagining that foldLeft is identical to foldl. Just a little stunted as to where to start

Comment: Start by writing down the types that `f` and `base` must have. (I accidentally wrote `foldLeft` in the first sentence of my above comment, where I meant `f`.) That should make it reasonably obvious what they should be.

Comment: I figure that `base` should be `fs`. I've added expected results of the functions to my post. `f` should be a function that somehow stacks the function of the previous term with 'fs' at the center. I could be far off here, im pretty lost.

Comment: I understand what you want the function to do (and `foldl` does work just as well as `foldr`, I checked). But `base` cannot be `fs`, as they have different types. Seriously, write down the types of `f` and `base` - it will make things a lot clearer. You'd be surprised how far you can get with Haskell just by making sure types match up. Another way to think about `base` is: what do you expect `pipe` to do if given an empty list?

Comment: Ok, I've written down the types of `f` and `base` as:
`f :: (a -> b -> a)`
and base should be an integer 
I'm still unsure as to how to apply the term of the list as a function in `f`

Comment: Those types aren't correct. Compare the type of `foldl` with those of your list and the final output that you want.

Comment: Another way to look at it is: you want to combine a bunch of functions into a single function. What tools (= functions or operators) does Haskell provide for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with foldl it should be:

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe fs = foldl (\rs f -> f . rs) id fs
```

or with an eta:

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe = foldl (\rs f -> f . rs) id
```

with another eta:

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe = foldl (.) id
```

taking your example:

```
pipe [(\x -> x * 4), (\x -> x + x)] 3
=> 24
```

Answer (score 0):

`pipe` can actually be made much simpler than you'd think, and there's no need to use the rather inefficient `foldl` (you can see this even in your own parentheses—they're right-associative): just `flip (foldr id)`. Steps to get there:

```
pipe [f1,...,fn] x
f1 (f2 (... (fn x)))            -- your definition of pipe
id f1 (id f2 (... (id fn x)))   -- id x = x
foldr id x [f1,...,fn]          -- the definition of foldr
```